# Triangulations with discrete metrics and conformal equivalence

Tags: discrete-geometry, riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, triangulations, conformal-maps

A discrete metric for a triangulation of a 2-dimensional manifold is a map associating $\mathbb{R}_+$-valued lengths to all edges, such that the triangle inequality holds on every triangle. In many references, such as [1], it is stated that scaling the lengths of all edges incident to a fixed vertex $v$ by a constant factor $\alpha$ constitutes a discrete conformal transformation, which I'll call $S(v,\alpha)$. Every triangulation $T$ with discrete metric yields a "manifold" $M(T)$ which is flat everywhere except for the vertices where it has cone-like singularities. According to [2], every point in conformal moduli space can be represented by such a flat manifold with cone-like singularities.

My question: Are the original manifold $M(T)$ and the manifold $M(S(v,\alpha)T)$ after rescaling around one vertex of $T$ really conformally equivalent?

If this is indeed the case, then what is wrong with the following paradox: First notice that for any pair of triangles adjacent to the same edge $e$, forming a convex $4$-gon, flipping between the two ways of decomposing the 4-gon into two triangles is a move $P(e)$ which changes $T$ but not $M(T)$. Now for a vertex $v$ and an adjacent edge $e$, consider the combination
$$ P(e)^{-1} \circ S(v,\alpha^{-1}) \circ P(e)  \circ S(v,\alpha)\;. $$
This will change the length of the edge $e$, but will leave the lengths of all other edges invariant. Changing the length of an individual edge seems to powerful for a conformal transformation, even though the application of the sequence above is restricted to cases where the corresponding $4$-gons are convex. Concretely, a seeming contradiction can be obtained by considering an untwisted ratio-$1$ conformal torus triangulated by $10\times 10$ unit squares with each square subdivided into two triangles. All $4$-gons are convex, so we can use the move above to change the length of every horizontal edges to $1+\epsilon$ for small enough constant epsilon, and change the length of all diagonal edges to $\sqrt{1+(1+\epsilon)^2}$. This yields a torus of ratio $1+\epsilon$ which is not conformally equivalent to the original torus of ratio $1$.

[1] "Conformal Equivalence of Triangle Meshes", http://www.multires.caltech.edu/pubs/ConfEquiv.pdf, Definition 2.2

[2] https://mathoverflow.net/a/346260/115363

Comment: I don't think their discrete conformal equivalence matches with conformal equivalence indeed

Comment: @alesia: Oh, that's a bit disappointing! Is there any way to fix this? I guess it cannot be as easy as using some non-linear function for edge length rescaling; the paradox of rescaling an individual edge would still work in this case.

Comment: I think their approach might converge to the right thing for dense triangulations, but to get the exact right thing I doubt one can simply change the edge lengths of a fixed triangulation (whatever the scheme used)

Comment: @alesia: Hmm, but surely there are changes of edge lengths which correspond to exact conformal maps. Are you saying that there is no such change of edge lengths which is local, in the sense that it depends only on edge lengths in some constant-combinatorial-size region?

Comment: I tend to think that the set of edge lengths that give rise to conformally equivalent surfaces might not be very easy to understand, but i'm not a specialist